# Can I read pixel data from an SDL_Texture after using SDL_LockTexture()

Tags: c, sdl, pixel, sdl-2

I am working on a function that will "map" a texture onto a target texture (where both textures are created with the SDL_TextureAccess hint "SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING"). That is to say, wherever there is a transparent pixel (specifically RGB all 255 and A 0) on the base image the corresponding pixel will also be made to be transparent on the mapped image. The image below shows my desired results (each image is 64x64 pixels). The left side is without mapping.

[image: Comparison Image]

Originally I accomplished this just using SDL_Textures and the code for this can be found below (error checking omitted for brevity):

```c
void MapOntoTexture(SDL_Texture* base, SDL_Texture* mapped)
{
    Uint32 base_format = 0;
    int height = 0;
    SDL_QueryTexture(base, &base_format, NULL, NULL, &height);
    SDL_PixelFormat* baseFormat = SDL_AllocFormat(base_format);
    
    Uint32 mapped_format = 0;
    int mappedHeight = 0;
    SDL_QueryTexture(mapped, &mapped_format, NULL, NULL, &mappedHeight);
    SDL_PixelFormat* mappedFormat = SDL_AllocFormat(mapped_format);
    
    void* basePixels = NULL;
    int basePitch = 0;
    SDL_LockTexture(base, NULL, &basePixels, &basePitch);
    Uint32* realBasePixels = basePixels;
    
    void* mappedPixels = NULL;
    int mappedPitch = 0;
    SDL_LockTexture(mapped, NULL, &mappedPixels, &mappedPitch);
    Uint32* realMappedPixels = mappedPixels;
    
    int basePixelsInt = (basePitch / 4) * height;
    int mappedPixelsInt = (mappedPitch / 4) * mappedHeight;
    Uint32 baseTransparent = SDL_MapRGBA(baseFormat, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00);
    Uint32 mappedTransparent = SDL_MapRGBA(mappedFormat, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < basePixelsInt; i++)
    {
        if (realBasePixels[i] == baseTransparent)
        {
            realMappedPixels[i] = mappedTransparent;
        }
    }
    
    SDL_UnlockTexture(base);
    SDL_UnlockTexture(mapped);
    
    SDL_FreeFormat(baseFormat);
    SDL_FreeFormat(mappedFormat);
}
```

However, re-reading through the SDL wiki I found this quote:

> As an optimization, the pixels made available for editing don't necessarily contain the old texture data. This is a write-only operation, and if you need to keep a copy of the texture data you should do that at the application level.

The write-only part of that concerns me despite the fact that this works in my program. However, I suspect this is a case of undefined behaviour nose demons. Therefore, I wrote a different function which takes advantage of surfaces instead (and then later converts them to textures). I recognize surfaces may need to be locked and they are in the actual code but once again it is omitted for brevity. Here's the code:

```c
void MapOntoSurface(SDL_Surface* base, SDL_Surface* mapped)
{
    int basePixelsInt = (base->pitch / 4) * base->h;
    int mappedPixelsInt = (mapped->pitch / 4) * mapped->h;
    Uint32 baseTransparent = SDL_MapRGBA(base->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00);
    Uint32 mappedTransparent = SDL_MapRGBA(mapped->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00);
    
    Uint32* realBasePixels = base->pixels;
    Uint32* realMappedPixels = mapped->pixels;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < basePixelsInt; i++)
    {
        if (realBasePixels[i] == baseTransparent)
        {
            realMappedPixels[i] = mappedTransparent;
        }
    }
    
    //Use "mapped" surface to create texture later
}
```

Admittedly, this is significantly simpler than the texture related one but I would rather not do it since it is somewhat inelegant when I have to reconvert the surfaces to textures. So finally my question is: can I use the first version without any worry of undefined behaviour or should I use the second one?

Comment: Generally in SDL a write operation whether to a screen or texture is one-way. Meaning you generate the pixels you want to write and perform the write (blit to the screen, etc.) What I take that to mean is you cannot expect to read back from the area of the texture you modified to recover the same data. So the write-only and copy at the application level means that if you need to preserve a copy of the data you are about to write (for further changes, etc..) do so, don't expect to read back what you have written for the next modification. (this is my "general" understanding).

Comment: @David C. Rankin So from your understanding would you say that if I were to read from a texture exactly one time then it would be ok?

Comment: My understanding is that after writing to a texture, you have no guarantee of being able to read that same information back. SDL is free to treat the memory associated with the texture as a scratch-pad after the texture itself has been set for display. That's why you have the note about making the copy if you need to save what you write. My read of `SDL_QueryTexture()` is that it returns the attributes of the texture, not necessarily each individual pixel (it can, but isn't guaranteed -- thus the copy). I don't do enough SDL to be an authority, but this is my read of the note.

Comment: That's right, you don't read texture data back. As I see it locked buffer contents are only preserved in opengl renderer implementation, and even there it can go wrong if you combine it with `UpdateTexture`. Besides, `LockTexture` is only usable on streaming textures; are all of your textures flagged as streaming? If so, do you realise it doubles memory usage on opengl renderer (the only renderer besides software that *currently* don't dispose locked data)? That texture remapping you're doing - is it known before program lauch or dynamic and could change every frame?

Comment: @keltar All of my textures are created with the streaming flag (see edit). I didn't realize that this doubles the memory usage but only the textures that need to use this function are created with the streaming flag (only a small amount of textures need to use this function). The texture remapping IS known before the program launch but if I created all the textures prior to launch I would be left with an additional ~25000 extra images for my game. This wasn't a cost I wanted to offload onto my user.

Comment: @SafelyFast "only the textures that need to use this function are created with the streaming flag" so you know which textures needs it. Then consider keeping pixels in RAM for that textures only; even better, alpha channel could be extracted separately to reduce memory usage; it could even be packed into bitmask. If target texture don't need its original content (sounds like it is the case as you modify it) it could be patched at loading stage without keeping extra copy in memory.

Comment: @keltar I am currently caching the pixels, albeit in an SDL_Surface* for convenience. I have a structure composed of an SDL_Texture*, SDL_Surface*, and SDL_Rect which allows me to update the texture as required. I suppose I could keep just the pixels and pixel format as well as an alpha channel but I am unconvinced that the increase in complexity is worth the decrease of (V)RAM usage. Each texture needing the use of this feature will use approximately 1MB of RAM while using your method of using an alpha channel will save 25% of this cost...

Comment: @keltar with how much memory computers have nowadays this doesn't seem to be a useful tradeoff in this case but I will keep it in mind. I will, however, look into patching the texture at the loading stage since this is a good optimization that I didn't consider.

Comment: @SafelyFast keeping only alpha will save 75%, not 25 (1 byte per pixel instead of 4). Packing to bitmask will be 8 times lower than that (1 bit per pixel), but it is a bit more difficult to implement. It will also improve performance as you access much lower tightly packed memory range. But of course if there are few of that textures it may be not noticeable.